# Sending screenshots taking too much memory

Tags: c#, memory, screenshot, nancy

I am trying to make a small application to serve screenshot of entire screen through network. I want it to be able to serve one every 1-2 seconds through LAN. I thought it won't be a big problem, so I chose C# and nancy www self host (as the easiest option). Now, the speed is allright for my needs, but it seems to be taking way too much memory, and it grows with time. It seems to settle on taking about 3.5 GB RAM and from then no longer grows, but that's not an acceptable amount - even with big resolution (mine is 2560x1440).

Is my code bad, or is nancy not suitable for handling many big responses, or maybe C# method of capturing screen is poorly optimized and I should try pinvoke methods? Or maybe it's just a terrible way to do it and I should try something more advanced, like using VNC library?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    private Bitmap bitmapScreenCapture;
    private Graphics graphics;
    private Object lockMe = new object();
    private MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["image"] = parameters =>
        {
            lock (lockMe)
            {
                GC.Collect();

                if (bitmapScreenCapture == null || bitmapScreenCapture.Width != Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width || bitmapScreenCapture.Height != Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
                {
                    if (bitmapScreenCapture != null)
                    {
                        bitmapScreenCapture.Dispose();
                    }
                    bitmapScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapScreenCapture);
                }

                graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                    0, 0,
                    bitmapScreenCapture.Size,
                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                bitmapScreenCapture.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                return new Response()
                {
                    Contents = stream => memoryStream.CopyTo(stream)
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you declare your objects inside of your method instead of at the class level?

Comment: You should try cleaning all the data from the MemoryStream.

Comment: Make sure you are disposing of disposable objects like Graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as possible, keep variables in the most local scope possible, and dispose of what you can.

Part of your issue may be that you're new'ing up a `Graphics` instance repeatedly, but never disposing of the old reference. The GC will collect it eventually, but you can place your code in a `using` block to let it know you're done with it.

I haven't tested this, but here I've made your instances local, and disposed of the `Graphics` and `Bitmap` instances. I didn't dispose of the `MemoryStream` since I'm not sure it will successfully return the value if you do, but you could play around with it.

```
var screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height))
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.Left, screen.Bounds.Top, 0, 0, screen.Bounds.Size);
    }

    var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    imageStream.Position = 0;

    return new Response()
    {
        Contents = stream => memoryStream.CopyTo(stream)
    };
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks to that I've realized what I've done really wrong: it was my lack of experience using Nancy. It's creating a new module instance for each request, which I completely didn't think of... Declaring properties as static fixes that as well, so non-local variables wasn't the real problem here ;)

Comment: @trakos Using statics in your Nancy module is going to cause intermittent bugs due to a race when a second request starts before the first request completes.

Comment: @ScottS I don't expect more than one concurrent client, so, as seen in the code above, there is a lock covering entire request handler (which now is static as well). That should be enough, right?

Comment: @trakos, the lock will prevent races so you are likely safe in your particular situation.  In most situations using statics in a web service is going to get you into trouble, so I strongly advise you not to settle on that solution.